# Python response JSON to MySQLDB comes back empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

My Goal is to parse the API via pagination. Store as a JSON feed, and then send it off to the MySQL DB. Once stored, I want to check if any new rows have been added, if so delete the database and add all new rows. (maybe not the best approach?)  However for some strange reason nothing is storing in mySQLDB anymore, and my prints aren't working. Any thoughts on what I messed up?

**PYTHON**

```
import requests
import json

def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='watch',
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

#init db
db = dbconnect()
cursor = db.cursor()

# Start getting all entries
def get_all_cracked_entries():
    # results will be appended to this list
    all_time_entries = []

    # loop through all pages and return JSON object
    for page in range(1, 4):
        url = "https://api.watch.com/api?page="+str(page)
        response = requests.get(url=url).json()
        all_time_entries.append(response)
        page += 1

        for product in response:
            print("id:", product["_id"])
            print("title:", product["title"])
            print("slug:", product["slug"])
            print("releaseDate:", product["releaseDate"])
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO jsondump (id, title, slug, releaseDate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (product["_id"], product["title"], product["slug"], product["releaseDate"]))
            db.commit()

            #Check Row Count
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `jsondump`")
            cursor.fetchall()
            rc = cursor.rowcount
            print("%d"%rc)

            if rc > rc+1:
                 rs = cursor.fetchall()
            else:
                cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE jsondump")
                for product in response:
                    print("id:", product["_id"])
                    print("title:", product["title"])
                    print("slug:", product["slug"])
                    print("releaseDate:", product["releaseDate"])
                    print('---')
                    db = dbconnect()
                    cursor = db.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO jsondump (id, title, slug, releaseDate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (product["_id"], product["title"], product["slug"], product["releaseDate"]]))
                    db.commit()
                    cursor.close()

    # prettify JSON
    data = json.dumps(all_time_entries, sort_keys=True, indent=0)
    #
    return data
```

**SAMPLE JSON**

````
[{
"_id":"xxxxxxx",
"releaseDate":"2020-02-13T21:00:00-03:00",
"slug":"table-manners",
"title":"Table Manners","
}]  ```
````

Comment: So you have 2 parts here the `requests.get` and all the database interaction later ... you mentioned "prints aren't working" maybe there is nothing on the response and there is nothing to loop